# Assigning numeric values to character elements of data frame

Tags: r

I have 16*3 data frame. Elements in data frame are character e.g., A, B, C... How can I assign them values e.g., A= 2, B=5, C=4 in R?

Comment: `?gl` might be useful, and `?levels` too.

Comment: Reproducible examples are useful as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can map the values from the vector you created:

```
relevel <- function(df, levelmap) {
  df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) levelmap[as.character(x)]);df
}
```

The function subsets the values based on the map vector.

**Example**

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("A", "C", "C", "A"), y=c("B", "C", "B", "A"), z=c("A", "B", "C", "A"))
df
  x y z
1 A B A
2 C C B
3 C B C
4 A A A

newlevels <- c(A=2,B=5,C=4)

relevel(df, newlevels)
  x y z
1 2 5 2
2 4 4 5
3 4 5 4
4 2 2 2
```

The `newlevels` vector is a special vector called a named vector. It's very helpful as it can be referenced by both its names and its indices. `newlevels["A"]` and `newlevels[1]` both return the same output. This simplifies what in other languages would require hash tables or other lookup arrays.

Comment: Thanks... and I want to save result in new data frame... how will it work?

Comment: `newdf <- relevel(df, newlevels)`

Comment: I want the row wise mean ... rowMeans(as.data.frame[newdf[1,]]) is not working, it says x must be numeric.

Comment: Works for me: `rowMeans(newdf)
[1] 3.000000 4.333333 4.333333 2.000000` If you only want a particular row, `rowMeans(newdf)[1] [1] 3`

Comment: I am assigning Triangular fuzzy number e.g.,  A=(0.9,0.9,1.0), B=(0.7,0.9,1.0), C=(0.9,0.9,1.0). If first row contains A, B, C, I want element wise Mean.... 0.9+0.7+0.9/3, 0.9+0.9+0.9/3, 1.0+1.0+1.0/3. rowMeans working fine but not in data frames or in table

Comment: It is not clear from the comment what you would like to do next. You are now expanding your question beyond the original post. If you would like further help, please post another question.